# Prospensity-score matching without replacement in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, replace, matching

I have 2 dataframes, `df_treatment` and `df_control`. I want to match each element in `df_treatment` to its closest match in `df_control` based on their propensity score (already calculated).

The problem is the only ways I've found are based on the KNN Nearest Neighbors algorithm but with replacement so an element in `df_control` might be matched with multiple elements in `df_treatment`.

I'm trying to find a way to match this two datasets based on their propensity score as to reduce confounding bias but using a matching method without replacement as I have to match each element in the treatment group to its closest propensity score-based match, and the elements in the control group can only be matched to one element in the treatment group.

I'm trying for the algorithm to delete the elements in the original `df_control` once they're matched to an element in the treatment group (and "moved" to `df_matched_control`), but I haven't found a way to solve this.

I've checked these two notebooks for Propensity Score Matching with KNN in Python, but both use with replacement matching:

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ethen8181/machine-learning/blob/master/ab_tests/causal_inference/matching.ipynb

https://github.com/konosp/propensity-score-matching/blob/main/propensity_score_matching_v2.ipynb

The R package MatchIt has Nearest Neighbors match which solves this problem but I can't find anything similar in Python.

Comment: Hello Zenit, I am also interested in this matter. Have you found any solutions yet?

Comment: Hi Alis, sadly I have not found a solution yet. I have since used R for Propensity Score Matching with much more success. If it is helps you any, R libraries "MatchIt" and "Matching" worked really well for me and both have the option to match with or without replacement.